# Are there any properties in an app configuration (plists and such) that could cause push notifications not to show in the notification center?

Tags: ios, notifications, apns

I am posting this again with more clarity.

[User reporting that Push Notification doesn't always show in the notification center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377573/user-reporting-that-push-notification-doesnt-always-show-in-the-notification-ce?noredirect=1#comment509275_377573)

I have an app. My client is reporting that push notifications from the app DO NOT go into the notification center.

To me, that sounds like an OS settings issue, as mentioned by the commenter on the other issue.

However I want to get authoritative information on whether there's any way - any possible way, that this is due to some sort of misconfiguration of plist files or something else in the actual development of the app.

I've googled for this, I've searched for this, and I haven't found anything, which is why I am asking here.

So my question is - is there any type of misconfiguration, in the actual build of the app (which I have developed) that could lead to push notifications not appearing in the notification center? Note, they DO appear at the top of the user's screen, and I personally see them in my notification center, as do most users to my knowledge.

The user in question is on iOS 13, on an iPhone 11. Personally, I think it's an OS settings issue, but they're a non-technical user and I am trying to troubleshoot if it could **possibly** be something on my end.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If your original question needs clarification, *edit* that question instead so it can be reviewed and reopened.

Comment: Also, questions about software development are off-topic here but can be asked on Stack Overflow. As a developer you have access to the full documentation on developer.apple.com, including the Notification API and its configuration.

Comment: @nohillside The question was closed, and the notice at the top of the question literally says, "Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one." - the modal is telling me to post a new question. I am getting conflicting information here.

Comment: Well, the new one you posted is a development question and therefore off-topic. As already explained, please edit the original question to make it more than „please look something up in the manual for me“. Maybe you already did that, then please add the things you‘ve asked the user to try.